# local smtp mail server could not send mail(Connection timed out)

Tags: timeout, sendmail, spf, postfix-mta

ERORR：

```
Feb 14 14:09:04 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.94]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 14:09:34 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[104.44.194.231]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 14:10:04 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[207.46.8.167]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 14:10:34 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: connect to mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 14:11:04 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 14:11:04 es1 postfix/smtp[16443]: 228D519C06D: to=<xxxx@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=395818, delays=395668/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25: Connection timed out)
```

**I've host Mail Server on CentOS 6 with *Postfix/Dovecot*, I can receive mail from outside, but can't not sending mail to outside.**

Things I've done:

Add spf record to dns, also validate successfully from http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?

```
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all
```

Note:

I've change the default port 25 to 26 due to ISP block issue by adding  *etc/postfix/master.cf*

```
26 inet n - n - - smtpd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP is probably blocking outbound port 25. Its very common. Your SPF record and inbound SMTP port makes no difference. I suggest you contact your ISP.

Comment: I figured out the reason as your said, my ISP block it any way.